# Can't validate date in c#

Tags: c#, .net

This code doesn't seem to work when I am writing `29/07/1990` in the textbox. It always goes to the else statement.

```
  string date = tbDate.Text;

  DateTime Test;
  if (DateTime.TryParseExact(date, "MM/dd/yyyy", null, DateTimeStyles.None, out Test) == true) {
    Console.WriteLine("Date OK");
  } else {
    Console.WriteLine("Date Not OK");
  }
```

Comment: Do you consider `29` to be a valid Month??

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are supplying a non-US format date and trying to parse it with a US-format parser. Change "MM/dd/yyyy" to "dd/MM/yyyy":

```
if (DateTime.TryParseExact(date, "dd/MM/yyyy", null, DateTimeStyles.None, out Test) == true) {
    ...
```

Comment: Too many hours of coding now, what a bad misstake :S

Comment: Well it still goes to the else statement?

Comment: Changed `/` to use `-` instead and it's working okay

Answer (score 2):

You have specified "MM/dd/yyyy" as format for parsing string to date.

So if you're writing `29/07/1990` - it considered as 29 month and 7 day - this surely is not a valid date.

Probably you need "dd/MM/yyyy" format string.

Answer (score 0):

29 is not a valid month so naturally the parsing will fail.